# Stuck in pet moving situation

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am stuck here in jungle. its been 2 days i have been thinking how am I going to take these both ocelots back to my base.
[image]

---

The first thought in my mind was going via nether. however I didn't find any nice path in spectator world (world with same seed + gamemode sp). so pathing in nether is major problem. I will have to do in survival + Protect these kittens from taking any damage. So overall nether is risky place.

here is what I have thought

**Path 1 (red path):**

going from,

A -> B : sprinting with the cats till swamp.

B : get some slimeball and make lead so the pet ski can be done ([Reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LMy2rji1uqY&feature=youtu.be); Indicated by dotted line on map)

B -> taiga -> C : using the above water ski method get ocelots and wolves from taiga to home location

**Path 2 (yellow path):**

going from,

A -> B : use boat to go to swamp quickly.

B : get some slimeball and make lead.

B -> A -> taiga -> C : go to jungle. make ocelots do water ski till taiga. next let wolves + cats do water ski till home location.

**Path 3 (light pink path)**

use land to move all pets; no need to gather slime and make lead.
[image]

---

I am assuming it is going to take about 5 to 6 hours at max (If I do correctly).
**Which method is optimum?**
any other suggestions (no nether) would be good.

Comment: for those who are wondering why my screen is portrait, http://i.imgur.com/4lNUzdQ.jpg  My monitor is broken. it is gone for repair. this is just temporary solution

Comment: Your pets will teleport to you if you get too far away and they are not sat down. Just make them all stand up, then take a boat to somewhere close to C and when you get out of the boat, they will all teleport near to you.

Comment: @Andrew Yes I know that. When I move far away(by boat), chunks get unloaded. and a pet in unloaded chunk does not teleport to player

Comment: @Fennekin They will teleport to you before you unload the chunks, normally also in the water (they can swim). Generally. However I could imagine this to be a problem if you use very low render distance. In this case - and if you really don't want to use the nether whatsoever - you should be able to put them in a boat with you and transport them one-by-one. Not a huge fan of the lead idea, leads break too quickly too often.

Comment: @Fennekin that monitor is hilarious, but if you generalized this question more it could be an amazing question/answer about optimal methods of animal movement.

Comment: @KeaganDalley Actually the calculation part was brain and time consuming. and speaking of generalisation the path may vary from location to location. And about the monitor. the monitor power supply system had failed. now it is replaced and now it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I done some math for the optimum path.

Route A is yellow path

Route B is Red path

[image]
The number 1,2,3,4,5,6 represent A,B,T,Z,C,J respectively.
on right side co-ordinate of block in x,z are filled.

distance from respective points is calculated and then from [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Transportation), time is calculated.

[image]

---

**So from calculation Red path is optimum path.**