# water-ski failed. what can be done

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Everything was going according to planned (see [Stuck in pet moving situation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/271964/stuck-in-pet-moving-situation)). The idea of water-ski was going great. but all of sudden, my leads broke. they are probably in bottom of ocean. I can not risk going down due to fear of drowning.
and now cats are just swimming in the Ocean. I have few slime balls in my inventory but I don't have string. also I cannot place crafting table in middle of ocean. I was thinking of going to a shore killing some spiders and crafting the leads again. but I don't have guarantee how long those leads are going to sustain. I have over 2.5 thousand blocks to travel.

Is there any other way to move these pets to my base?
[image]

Comment: I took the risk of going down to get the leads. luckly i had few fences so I was able to breathe while at ocean floor. but when I reached the floor, cats teleported there got drowned while trying to get to surface. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just walking home. They should teleport when you arrive on land. They won't teleport until you've hit a solid block. If this does not work try keeping the cords. (X,Y,Z) To go home, and craft leads.

Comment: This teleportation only occurs if the chunk is loaded in which the cats were last standing

Comment: After moving over the ocean there is no possibility of loading chunk far away where that cat was